# How can we send Sabre Web Services requests using Sabre Scribe? (Currently I read Profiles using EPS)

Tags: sabre

Currently I am able to read Sabre Profiles using EPS through Sabre Scribe. But how do I get to send other RQ (like PriceItinerary, GetReservationRQ) and get RS through Sabre scribe? Any ideas?? Thanks...

Comment: You might need to get in touch with their support

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the only Web Services information available in in Sabre Red is Sabre Profile data.

I believe you would need to use a Sabre Red App to access any other web services data from Sabre Red. You can use the native search commands in Sabre Red using Scribe to accomplish many of the same tasks, however (e.g. WPNI entries).